# What to do when my Data source is not supported by Azure Synapse's Data Flow?

Tags: azure, transformation, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I am trying to transform data from Salesforce before loading it to dedicated SQL pool.
When I try to create a dataset from Synapse's Dataflow, I am not able to choose Salesforce a Data store:
[image]

Can anyone suggest how to transform data from Salesforce or any other Datasource that is not supported by Dataflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores), Currently Dataflows **does not support Salesforce** data as source or sink.

If you want, you can **raise the feature request** in the Synapse portal.

[image]

As an alternate, you can use [Copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce?tabs=data-factory) in the Azure Data factory to **copy** data from **Salesforce to Dedicated SQL pool** and then you can **transform** it using Dataflows in synapse from **Dedicated SQL DB to Dedicated SQL DB**.

Follow the below steps to achieve your requirement:

- First create a [Data Factory Workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal#create-a-data-factory).
- Select the **Author** hub and a **create a pipeline**. Now, **drag the copy activity** from the workspace and select the source. You can see that **Salesforce is supported** when you select new source dataset. Select it and create a linked service for that.

[image]

- Now, select the **sink dataset** and click on Azure Synapse analytics.

[image]

- Create a linked service for the **Dedicated SQL database** and select it.

[image]

- Then, you can select the table in the Dedicated SQL and **copy your data** by running this.
- After this copy, go to **Synapse workspace** and click on the Source of the Dataflow.
  Select the **Azure Synapse Analytics in source** and click on continue.

[image]

- Now, click on **New** to create **linked service for the SQL DB**. Give the subscription and server name and authenticate with your database.

[image]

- After the creation of linked service, select it and give your **table** which is result of the copy in the DB.

[image]

- Now, go to sink and select Azure Synapse Analytics and create another linked service for it as same above and select the **resultant table** in DB which you want after transform.

[image]

- By following the above process, we can achieve the transformation from **Salesforce data to Dedicated SQL DB**.

> Can anyone suggest how to transform data from Salesforce or any other Datasource that is not supported by Dataflow?

You can try this approach for the data stores which are not supported by the Data flows and please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats) to check various data stores supported by **Copy activity** before doing this process for the other data stores.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But won't this approach cost us more storage and compute?

Comment: Yeah, It costs more storage and compute. But in this type of cases where data stores not supported you can try this kind of approaches.